# Why is the date entry in PHPMyAdmin is 0000-00-00?

Tags: php, mysql, date

```
  <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO PatientData (username, Date, GlucoseReading, Carbohydrates, InsulinUsed, InsulinType,WhichMeal)
VALUES 

('$_Post[username]', '$_POST[Date]', '$_POST[GlucoseReading]', '$_POST[Carbohydrates]', '$_POST[InsulinUsed]','$_POST[InsulinType]', '$_POST[WhichMeal]' )";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What does `$_POST["date"]` contain? Also your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: I assume that your "Date"-field is of the type "date". It is important to provide a date in the exact wanted format so the date can be saved.

Comment: Yea it is correct, it inserts if i change it too a different format, i need to protect against sql injection still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what the previous posters have said, make sure your date is valid. For example, 2011-02-31 is an invalid date, which MySQL will turn into 0000-00-00.

> Illegal DATETIME, DATE, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00 00:00:00' or '0000-00-00'). ([MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html))

Comment: Briliant, il slap in some validation!

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST["DATE"]` is apparently of not correct format or empty.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons are

1. May be your `$_POST[Date]` is empty
2. Format of date is not `yyyy-mm-dd` mysql accept date in format `yyyy-mm-dd`

check for these and make sure you must protect your queries against SQL Injection.

Comment: Thanks, how could I protect this against sql injection?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your post title i believe you have column as date.

In mysql Date field is of format yyyy-mm-dd.

If you try to enter anything else that wont resemble as above formatted date it inserts 0000-00-00.

To rectify it, rather than entering date directly into database format it as below

date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST[Date]))

also one more piece of advice seeing your current code, it seems the code is prone to sql injection attack, sanitize data before inserting into db.

Comment: Thanks sudesh, do you have any ideas about how i can make this more secure from sql injection?

Comment: Just use addslashes or mysql_real_escape_string functions to sanitize the raw input from post